# (Django) A request was passed with missing value for 'category' which the code could not process. I need to catch this exception and handle it

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

An AssertionError was raised where a negative value was passed in the api request:

```
AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.
  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "api/views.py", line 1811, in lots
    sale_id
  File "api/views.py", line 1684, in lots_v1
    datetime_now
  File "api/views.py", line 1409, in get_lot_items
    lots = paginator.page(page)
  File "django/core/paginator.py", line 62, in page
    return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __getitem__
    "Negative indexing is not supported."
```

This most likely resulted in 'infinite spinning wheel' showing to the user as the request was never finished due to the backend error.

I need to catch and handle these incorrect values for the parameters of the url.

Here is the definition of the paginator:
`def get_lot_items(
        lots,
        page,
        page_length,
        currency_dict,
        iClientNo,
        sale_finished,
        category,
        sale_status,
        authenticated,
        date_time
    ):
    # create lots items from the db query set

```
# paginate the lots
paginator = Paginator(lots, page_length)
try:
    lots = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    lots = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range, deliver last page of results.
    lots = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

items = []
flagged_items_collection = {}
if iClientNo:
    flagged_items_collection = get_flagged_items_collection2(
        iClientNo,
        lot_ids=[_lot.iSaleLotNoUnique for _lot in lots]
    )`
```

Also `page_length` is defined as:

`page_length = request.GET.get('length', None)
    try:
        page_length = int(page_length)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        page_length = None`

```
PAGE_LENGTH_DEFAULT = {'grid': 36, 'list': 10, 'results': 90}
if not page_length:
    try:
        page_length = PAGE_LENGTH_DEFAULT[category]
        status = 200
        msg = 'Everything is ok'
    except ValueError as e:
        pass`
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do exactly what you described. Is there any question in your "question"?

Comment: You'are showing the tracebacks, can you post your codes?

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised whenever you try to index a Django `Queryset` using negative indices. Here's the source code snippet:

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    """
    Retrieves an item or slice from the set of results.
    """
    if not isinstance(k, (slice,) + six.integer_types):
        raise TypeError
    assert ((not isinstance(k, slice) and (k >= 0)) or
            (isinstance(k, slice) and (k.start is None or k.start >= 0) and
             (k.stop is None or k.stop >= 0))), \
        "Negative indexing is not supported."
```

In all likelihood; the line causing this issue is:

```
return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
```

The value for either `bottom` or `top` is negative. What is your `per_page` configuration in the paginator class?

Comment: Thank you, my initial though was also the negative indexing on the QuerySet also, i’ll post my `per_page` configuration in the pagination class. @rtindru

Comment: Here is the code for the paginator:

`paginator = Paginator(lots, page_length)
    try:
        lots = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        lots = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range, deliver last page of results.
        lots = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)`

Comment: Can you add it to your question? Formatting is an issue in comments

Comment: Also, what is `page_length` defined as in `paginator = Paginator(lots, page_length)`?